# Tradingview Pine Script V5

Tags: pine-script

Does anybody know why the plot function is not displaying properly on my chart? The values are right but it just doesn't scale. The candles and the price scale changes but my chart stays the same. Any help would be appreciated!

My code is below:

```
//@version=5

indicator(title='EMA', shorttitle='EMA', overlay=false, scale=scale.right, precision=2, explicit_plot_zorder=true)

EMA200 = math.round(ta.ema(src, 200), 2)
opacity = input.int(title='Opacity', defval=0, minval=0, maxval=100)
    
plot(EMA200, color=color.new(color.fuchsia, opacity), style=plot.style_cross, title='200', join=true)
```

Comment: Nvm i got it. It was only a matter of settings with trading view where I need to "Pin To Scale" the indicator to the chart. It is resolved. Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Welcome :) Great work solving your own issue! You are [encouraged to answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so that it can serve as documentation for anyone else that has the same issue in the future. 48 hours  after posting you will be able to [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).